# Firefox 1440x900 Resolution Issue: Header and Footer is cut off

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Guys -

I have a problem regarding the Resolution Properties of Firefox 1440x900. 
The floating header, and the Footer is cut- off, and it is not scroll-able whether horizontal, or vertical.

Any ideas on how to fix this Issue?
This is the fragment of CSS for these affected objects:

**1) Footer**

```
#pageFooter {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**2) Persistent Header**

```
/* Line 49 */
.asmh-header, .asmh-header .container
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Line 67 */
.asmh-header .container
{
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

/* Line 77 */
.asmh-header .stick .container
{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Screenshot:
[Screenshot of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtVQ0.jpg)

Hoping for your thoughts, and responses
Thanks!

Comment: did you try `float:left` and `width:100%` to header and footer

Comment: Can you include your HTML?

Comment: Hi, Guys - I have tried to do the float: left, and the width: 100% but it seems I got the same result ): This is working fine in Chrome, it has the automatic scroll. However, Firefox doesn't accept